# Spinning element for form submit button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to include a spinning element for Bootstrap input loading text, as described in [this example](http://codepen.io/jmalatia/pen/HkmaA), but I am getting row string instead of actual html element. Can anyone give a hint why this could happen ?

[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8u3j3fw/) provided

```
<input type = 'submit' 
       class="btn btn-primary btm-sm pull-right" value="Оформить договор"     
       data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin '></i> @Localization.Uploading">
```

Comment: I looks as if you returned to a newline after `submit` make sure that that whole element is one line and not two. Also ` data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin '></i> @Localization.Uploading">` That looks as if the quotes are offset, I think you need to move the last quote outside the bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it is calling the `button` instead of the `input`

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/vXXgEr?editors=1010)

**HTML**

```
<button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btm-sm pull-right" value="Оформить договор" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin '></i> @Localization.Uploading">Оформить договор</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
  $this.button('loading');
    setTimeout(function() {
       $this.button('reset');
   }, 8000);
});
```